# PostgreSQL query performing differently on different versions/VMs

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently migrating a PostgreSQL database and performance on new infrastructure (v 11.12) is considerably worse than on our current infrastructure (v9.1), with the same data structure.

Query that is being executed:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT count(ab.uprn)
FROM (
    select (st_dump(st_setsrid(st_geomfromtext('POLYGON ((459879.14 148164.21, 459879.14 148264.21, 459979.14 148264.21, 459979.14 148164.21, 459879.14 148164.21))'),27700))).geom AS geompoly
    ) gp,
    os_addressbase.addressbase ab
INNER JOIN os_addressbase.addressbase_geom ag ON ab.uprn=ag.uprn
WHERE st_intersects(geompoly,geom)
    AND NOT st_touches(geompoly,geom)
```

Explain results below:

v9.1

```
Aggregate  (cost=412.24..412.25 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=3720.697..3720.698 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..412.12 rows=48 width=8) (actual time=297.023..3720.522 rows=23 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..227.15 rows=48 width=8) (actual time=174.664..2933.783 rows=23 loops=1)
              Join Filter: (_st_intersects(((st_dump('0103000020346C00000100000005000000F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241'::geometry)).geom), ag.geom) AND ((NOT (((st_dump('0103000020346C00000100000005000000F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241'::geometry)).geom) && ag.geom)) OR (NOT _st_touches(((st_dump('0103000020346C00000100000005000000F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241'::geometry)).geom), ag.geom))))
              ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=20.678..20.691 rows=1 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using ix_spatial_addressbase on addressbase_geom ag  (cost=0.00..152.45 rows=145 width=166) (actual time=152.371..2906.931 rows=23 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (((st_dump('0103000020346C00000100000005000000F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241'::geometry)).geom) && geom)
        ->  Index Scan using addressbase_os_pkey on addressbase ab  (cost=0.00..3.84 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=34.192..34.196 rows=1 loops=23)
              Index Cond: (uprn = ag.uprn)
Total runtime: 3721.705 ms
```

v11.2

```
Aggregate  (cost=3863931.90..3863931.91 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=5044025.124..5044025.129 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=1758059.87..3839039.08 rows=9957128 width=8) (actual time=5042708.712..5044025.078 rows=23 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (ag.uprn = ab.uprn)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..1860325.16 rows=9957128 width=8) (actual time=82.458..271.051 rows=23 loops=1)
              ->  Result  (cost=0.00..265.26 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=0.029..0.037 rows=1 loops=1)
                    ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5.27 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=0.027..0.034 rows=1 loops=1)
                          ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using ix_spatial_addressbase on addressbase_geom ag  (cost=0.42..1850.09 rows=996 width=40) (actual time=82.427..270.989 rows=23 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((((st_dump('0103000020346C00000100000005000000F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241'::geometry))).geom) && geom)
                    Filter: (_st_intersects((((st_dump('0103000020346C00000100000005000000F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241'::geometry))).geom), geom) AND ((NOT ((((st_dump('0103000020346C00000100000005000000F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241'::geometry))).geom) && geom)) OR (NOT _st_touches((((st_dump('0103000020346C00000100000005000000F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241'::geometry))).geom), geom))))
        ->  Hash  (cost=1267817.60..1267817.60 rows=29881348 width=8) (actual time=5042357.051..5042357.052 rows=29881349 loops=1)
              Buckets: 131072  Batches: 512  Memory Usage: 3325kB
              ->  Index Only Scan using addressbase_os_pkey on addressbase ab  (cost=0.56..1267817.60 rows=29881348 width=8) (actual time=0.035..5000410.264 rows=29881349 loops=1)
                    Heap Fetches: 29881349
Planning Time: 144.263 ms
Execution Time: 5044025.695 ms
```

Can someone suggest a reason for the different execustion plans? And possible settings changes I can look into? The same indexes and pkey have been applied to both instances.

Comment: the plans generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)` would be more helpful. The estimates on the 11 server are way higher than on the 9.1 server, so maybe you just have a lot more data in the newer server, or your statistics aren't up-to-date there.

Comment: EXPLAIN updated to include ANALYZE. As you can see vastly different execustion time. The data is identical.

Comment: You have substantially more rows in `addressbase_os_pkey`  29881349  vs 1